# Insert a row in a table in MySQL using C without using the INSERT keyword of MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, c

How can I insert a row in a table created using MySQL through a C program without using the INSERT keyword of MySQL?
I tried scouring through the source code of MySQL to find the code behind the INSERT keyword, but am unable to find anything.
Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: You mean connecting to MySQL with a C program or modifying the source of MySQL? Why do you want to do this without using `INSERT`?

Comment: Why would you want that? And how else would you insert a row if not with `INSERT`?

Comment: Why do you think that would be a good idea?  Most DBMS go to great lengths to ensure you can't, because when you do it, you will do it wrong.  How are you planning to update the indexes?  How are you planning to ensure the constraints on the table are satisfied?  How will you ensure the transactions are managed correctly?  How will you handle an extra allocation of disk space for the extra data? __Don't do it!__

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html ?

Comment: @Joe I was asking about connecting to MySQL as is done normally and then inserting rows into a table without using the INSERT command as done in the mysql_query(...).

Comment: Ok. You haven't answered 'why?'.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg A special requirement. :) And yes, it can be done without INSERT.

Comment: @Joe Need help with my assignment. :)

Comment: Is this a trick question? It's certainly a strange one. If you're asking us the answer you owe us a full reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE`

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

You would have to write your data to an external file first.

e.g.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

Comment: That's great help. Thanks!
But is there any alternate way possible? Without using external data files?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest, if you just want to avoid the exact keyword,  would probably be using [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html);

```
REPLACE INTO test (value) VALUES ('hello');
```

[A very simple SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b88ab/1).